# Change the background color of VS Code Python extension "cells"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the background color of the 'cell' boundaries in the Python file when using the MS Python extension for VS Code?

I would also like to be able to change the background or change some other visual element to distinguish between code and markdown cells.

This would make it easier to distinguish between the various elements on the code page.

Example:

```
Run Cell | Run All Cells
#%% [markdown]
# ## import packages

Run Cell | Run All Cells
#%%
import os
```

Comment: Yes, I want to change the color of the horizontal lines, which separates the cells.